# How to run a file in Eclipse as TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

I'm trying to run a very simple test on a mock API and when I go to the Eclipse to hit "Run as" it should have a testNG option, but instead has a greyed out (none applicable) option which you can't click. I tried installing TestNG JAR file but when I do, it has duplication errors on imports such as `Assert.assertEquals`.

```java
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import files.Payload;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

public class sumValidation {
    @Test
    public void sumOfCourses() {
        int sum = 0;
        JsonPath js = new JsonPath(Payload.CoursePrice());
        int courseSize = js.getInt("courses.size()");
        for(int i = 0; i < courseSize; i++) {
            int prices = js.getInt("courses.price[" + i + "]");
            int copies = js.getInt("courses.copies[" + i + "]");
            int amount = prices * copies;
            System.out.println(amount);
            sum = sum + amount;
            int purchaseAmount = js.getInt("dashboard.purchaseAmount");
            Assert.assertEquals(sum, purchaseAmount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can share your code directly in your question, rather through an image. That would be easier for others to quickly review and experiment.